# My HR style doesn't work like expected

Tags: html, css, styles, css-float, margin

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/V7wUv/2/

This is my HR style:

```
.page-content hr {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    border: 0 none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left; <-- take a close look at this
    height: 1px;
    margin: 50px auto; <-- take a close look at this
    max-width: 1120px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When I add `float:left;` I end up having `margin-top: 50px;` and `margin-bottom: 50px;` work correctly but not `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` (it just floats to the left all the time).

When I remove `float:left;` left and right margins work (it's properly centered) BUT `margin-top: 50px;` overlaps element above it and there is `0px` of margin.

Element above has this style if you need it:

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
}
```

I want my HR to be centered and with 50px top and bottom margin.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net so we can see exactly what you mean?

Comment: What happens if you do this: margin:0px auto; instead of margin:50px auto;

Comment: You could try containing the `<hr>` tag in a `<div>` with `overflow: hidden` set.

Comment: @SzerémiAttila It's not very convenient

Comment: @GazWinter - both have 0px of margin if there is no `float:left;`

Comment: If you have `width: 100%`, why do you need `auto` `margin`?

Comment: JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/V7wUv/2/

Comment: @SzerémiAttila It's not convenient to use additional DIV. I just want to use single HR each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    max-width: 220px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: :) Works. Simple and beautiful.

Comment: Setting the width did it for me